# In Kafka, How can we get the metadata of a topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

In Kafka, How can we get the metadata of a topic? If there is an option to get metadata and if I'm trying to get the metadata of a topic that doesn't existing, what happens?

Comment: What kind of metadata are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for details like how many partitions we have, who is the leader for each partition etc. By the way, I got it by running the  "bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-replicated-topic" command. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kafka-topics --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic name`

Or refer Javadoc for `AdminClient` class, or similar for a programming language of your choice